# Where is Databricks DBFS located?

Tags: amazon-web-services, databricks, azure-databricks

I have read through the documentation but I don't see much technical detail on DBFS.
Is this a hosted service or is it in the client's account? I assume it's not hosted, but I can't find it in my azure account or my aws account. I'm very interested in how this is set up and the technical details I can provide to clients. The most technical detail I can find is that there is a 2 gig file limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DBFS is the name for implementation of abstraction around underlying cloud storage, potentially of different types.  Usually, when people are referring to the DBFS, it comes to two things:

1. [DBFS Root](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/databricks-file-system#dbfs-root) - the main entry point of DBFS (`/`, `/tmp`, etc.).  On AWS you need to provision it yourself as S3 Bucket. On Azure it's created during workspace creation as a dedicated & isolated storage account in a separate managed resource group.  You can't update settings of that storage account after it's created, or access it directly.  That's why it's recommended not to store critical data in the DBFS Root.
2. Other storage accounts (you can also use S3 or GCS) that are mounted into a workspace. Although it's convenient to work with mounted storage, you need to understand that these mounts are available for all in workspace (except so-called passthrough mount)

Comment: so If I don't mount into the workspace, but lets say create a managed table... where does that live?? It gives me a DBFS path but I have gone through azure blob and the config for databricks in azure portal I don't see any data or indication of that data.

Comment: By default, managed table goes into DBFS Root, until you explicitly set location on the database. And DBFS Root is locked, and not accessible from the outside. You can always create an unmanaged table by adding `.option("path", "custom-path")` when writing data

Comment: So let me see if I digest this and feel free to say I'm thick. I have do not mount anything else on dbfs, now I create a managed table in azure. Are the parquet files located on the cluster or maybe there is a blob container dynamically created I have not found.

Comment: if you didn't specify path explicitly for table, or for database that contains that table, then data will go into default location `/user/hive/` that is on the DBFS Root, that is located in the storage account created inside the managed resource group

Answer (score -1):

Is it a hosted service. DBFS is provisioned as a part of workspace creation process.

If you prefer you can also mount storage accounts.

You can find more details about DBFS [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/databricks-file-system).